# How to read multiple csv or json files from an S3 into a spark jason

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I can read a csv file `myexample.csv` which is in an s3 buket into spark dataframe.

```
df = spark.read.csv(s3n://mybucket/myexample.csv)
```

But how can I read all the csv files in the bucket , for example *myexample1.csv, 
 myexample2.csv, myexample.csv* which are in the same bucket s3://mybucket into a dataframe.

`df = spark.read.csv(s3n://mybucket/)`  ..This works?

Comment: Haven't you tried it before posting it on StackOverflow?

Comment: You should try it with `s3a` instead of `s3n`.

Comment: Only if all the inner directories have the same partitions. Spark cannot read incompatible files (directory-wise). All files must be at the same level. E.g. s3a://bucket/foo=X/bar=Y/meow_i.csv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read many files of a particular type (CSV, JSONlines, Parquet, etc.), with [merge-compatible schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging) into a single dataset, the approach is as follows:

1. Generate a list of files (or directories if the file extensions are standard).
2. Use `spark.read.format(...).option("mergeSchema", true).load(files: _*)`

If some schema are not merge compatible, yet can be transformed into a common schema, the above should be repeated for each set of files with merge compatible schema, then the resulting dataframes should be projected into a common schema and unioned, e.g., something like:

```
val fileListsAndTransforms: Seq[Seq[String], DataFrame => DataFrame] = ...

fileListsAndTransforms.map { case (files, fn) =>
  spark.read.format(...).option("mergeSchema", true).load(files: _*)
    .transform(fn)
}.reduce(_ unionByName _)
```

The code examples are in Scala but they can be applied equally well in any Spark-supported language.